# Azure AKS - pod keep CrashLoopBackOff status

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to deploy application from my personal docker registry into Azure AKS pods.
I have python application that only logs some output:

```
import time
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('main')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

def main():
    logger.info('This is test')
    time.sleep(5)


while True:
    try:
        main()
    except Exception:
        logger.critical('Something critical.', exc_info=1)

    logger.info('Sleep for 5 seconds')
    time.sleep(5)
```

And this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

ARG APP_DIR=/app
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_DIR}
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN \
 apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev linux-headers && \
 python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir && \
 apk --purge del .build-deps

COPY app .

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "-u", "run.py" ]
```

I am able to run the container on my local computer, here some logs:

```
docker logs -tf my-container
2020-02-07T10:26:57.939062754Z 2020-02-07 10:26:57,938 - main - INFO - This is test
2020-02-07T10:27:02.944500969Z 2020-02-07 10:27:02,943 - main - INFO - Sleep for 5 seconds
2020-02-07T10:27:07.948643749Z 2020-02-07 10:27:07,948 - main - INFO - This is test
2020-02-07T10:27:12.953683767Z 2020-02-07 10:27:12,953 - main - INFO - Sleep for 5 seconds
2020-02-07T10:27:17.955954057Z 2020-02-07 10:27:17,955 - main - INFO - This is test
2020-02-07T10:27:22.960453835Z 2020-02-07 10:27:22,959 - main - INFO - Sleep for 5 seconds
2020-02-07T10:27:27.964402790Z 2020-02-07 10:27:27,963 - main - INFO - This is test
2020-02-07T10:27:32.968647112Z 2020-02-07 10:27:32,967 - main - INFO - Sleep for 5 seconds
```

I am trying to deploy pod with this yaml file with `kubectl apply -f onepod.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-container
  labels:
    platform: xxx
    event: yyy
    protocol: zzz
spec:
    imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistry
    containers:
    - name: my-container
      image: mypersonalregistry/my-container:test
```

The pod is created but keep `CrashLoopBackOff` status without any output logs via `kubectl logs` command. I tried `kubectl describe pod` but in events are nothing usefull:

```
Name:         my-container
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         aks-agentpool-56095163-vmss000000/10.240.0.4
Start Time:   Fri, 07 Feb 2020 11:41:48 +0100
Labels:       event=yyy
              platform=xxx
              protocol=zzz
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Pod","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"event":"yyy","platform":"xxx","protocol":"zzz"},"name":"my-container...
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.1.33
IPs:          <none>
Containers:
  my-container:
    Container ID:   docker://c497674f86deadca2ef874f8a94361e26c770314e9cff1729bf20b5943d1a700
    Image:          mypersonalregistry/my-container:test
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mypersonalregistry/my-container@sha256:c4208f42fea9a99dcb3b5ad8b53bac5e39bc54b8d89a577f85fec1a94535bc39
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 07 Feb 2020 12:28:10 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 07 Feb 2020 12:28:10 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  14
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-lv75n (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-lv75n:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-lv75n
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From                                        Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----                                        -------
  Normal   Scheduled  49m                    default-scheduler                           Successfully assigned default/my-container to aks-agentpool-56095163-vmss000000
  Normal   Pulled     48m (x5 over 49m)      kubelet, aks-agentpool-56095163-vmss000000  Container image "mypersonalregistry/my-container:test" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    48m (x5 over 49m)      kubelet, aks-agentpool-56095163-vmss000000  Created container my-container
  Normal   Started    48m (x5 over 49m)      kubelet, aks-agentpool-56095163-vmss000000  Started container my-container
  Warning  BackOff    4m55s (x210 over 49m)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-56095163-vmss000000  Back-off restarting failed container
```

How can I find out, why does it work on my computer but not in kubernetes cluster?

Comment: Can you give more output of `kubectl describe pod`? Or at least part of this command: `kubectl get pod termination-demo -o go-template="{{range .status.containerStatuses}}{{.lastState.terminated.message}}{{end}}"`?

Comment: Done, I added whole output of `kubectl desribe pod`.

Comment: Did you authenticate with a registry in order to pull a private image like [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) say?

Comment: Sure, I already create secret for my registry and pull image. Even from `kubectl describe pod` in events section you can see that `Container image mypersonalregistry/my-container:test already present on machine`.

Comment: I also tried `kubectl logs -p`, that should print logs from previous instance of the container, but it is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the porblem was with pulling latest version of my image. More [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images):

> The default pull policy is IfNotPresent which causes the Kubelet to skip pulling an image if it already exists.

So it still run the first version of `my-container` with tag `test` and never download new one even when it is in my registry.

Solution is add this line to yaml file:

```
imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Answer (score -1):

What you see is 100% expected. Your application sleeps for 10 seconds and exits. Kubernetes expects pods to run indefinitely. If pod exits for any reason (even with exit code 0) - Kubernetes will try to restart it. If pods exits many times - Kubernetes assumes that your pod is working incorrectly and changes its state to CrashloopingBackoff.

You may try to change your code to run in infinite loop and you will see that Kubernetes will be happy with it.

If you want to run tasks to finish - you may want to use Kubernetes Jobs. Kubernetes expects Jobs to complete with exit code 0.

Comment: Why would my application exits? There is `while True` condition. As I said, when I run it on my local machine, It just prints to logs.

Comment: In your case, if pod is restarted repeatedly, `kubectl logs -p` should show at least some logs from previous run.

Comment: yep, you are right, haven't spotted the "while True", sorry. You may want to include 'command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 100000"] to your Pod spec and try to launch app directly from inside the pod. Kubernetes sometimes may hide some errors from you.

Comment: I changed `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD [ "/bin/sleep", "5000"]` and it still does not work. Locally work perfectly.